# In MySQL 5, what's the convention for returning an error level and a resultset?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL 5, a stored procedure can return any number of output parameters, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test1`(IN in1 VARCHAR(64), IN in2, OUT out1  VARCHAR(64), OUT out2 INT, OUT out3 INT)
```

In MySQL 5, a stored procedure can also return/print a resultset, like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test2` ()
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM `table`;
END$$
```

This is nice and flexible.  So in trying to communicate with the outside world, what's the convention for using this flexibility to give notice of the **results** (if any) and the **errors** (if any)?

Examples:

1. Do we put error messages in our output parameters?  Do we put them in resultsets?
2. Do we print out multiple successive resultsets?  Or do we limit ourselves to one resultset?
3. Do we set the resultset to NULL if there are errors?
4. Do we use output paramenter integers for the errors, with 0 being error free?
5. Do we use output parameter VARCHARs for the errors, with '' (empty string) meaning error free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it makes sense to use [Signals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) for returning an error if it's supported by the server (5.5 and up).

Comment: I think I will call your answer the accepted answer, as it certainly expands my understanding and is what MySQL calls "the way to 'return' an error."  Let's wait and see if anything better turns up.  Thanks.